# Permission denied on function after schema copy

Tags: permissions, postgresql-9.6, schema-copy

I had one schema 'public' and simple function in the schema named 'isvalidoption'.

What was done:

- backup schema using pg_dump;
- rename schema to 'development';
- create new schema 'public';
- restore it from backup using pg_restore.

The problem:

- when I select from any table omitting schema prefix like 'SELECT *
  FROM mytable;' it's OK
- when I run function with schema prefix like 'SELECT public.isvalidoption();' or 'SELECT development.isvalidoption()' it's OK;
- when I run function omitting schema prefix like 'SELECT isvalidoption();' **I get ERROR: permission denied for function isvalidoption**

User has USAGE on both schemas and EXECUTE on function in both schemas also he is owner of the function in both schemas.

PostgreSQL version is 9.6.1.

'SELECT current_user;' shows correct user.

'SHOW search_path;' shows '"$user", public'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of reading of documentation I found that PosgreSQL first searches pg_catalog schema even before all schemas listed in search_path.

So checked pg_catalog catalog and I don't know why but my function was defined there and user postgres was the owner of the function.

I just deleted my function from pg_catalog and it's OK and works perfect as expected.

I still don't know how the function got there in pg_catalog.